# Distribution Profile Xcode 3.2.4 how?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am a little confused about where to get (or create) a distribution profile to submit my application to the iTunes Store. Previously I did this via the menu items from within the iPhone Developer Program > iTunes Connect, however now I can't see that option.

Inside `Xcode > Edit Project Settings > Code Signing > Any iOS Device` I can select "iPhone Developer" and its says (Currently matches: 'iPhone Developer: fuzzygoat') however if I select "iPhone Distribution" it says nothing.

Last time I did this (as I say above) I did this via iTunes Connect, downloaded the distribution profile, dragged it onto the Xcode icon to install and built my application ...

Can anyone help explain how this works now, I am using Xcode 3.2.4

**EDIT:** I have just found that when I logged into the devCenter my link was taking me directly to iTunes Connect, I have now noticed that there is a level above that which has the "iOS Provisioning Portal", I will have a look there, I think thats what I need.

Much appreciated

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello process of submit app on i-tune on store

first make the distribution profile for app store and then make build and go to i-tune connect and then fill all the field.
now download application loader and then open it and select profile for it ulpoad it
if not understand then tell me the full process that you follow