# How to associate my distribution identity with my provisioning profile in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios-provisioning

My question is exactly the same as the one listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830145/distribution-profile-xcode-3-2-4-how)

The reason I'm asking it again is that I'm not sure how to get into the provisioning portal as the original user asked.

Currently when I open the organizer through Xcode I see both identities but only 1 has the set of numbers following (and that is the developer identity)

How can I make this distribution identity valid so I can use it inside Xcode to build my project?

Currently getting the error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try going through the developer centre?

https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Note: you'll need to be a member of the iOS programme to access this site.